# GeoPandas - middle category skipped when using UserDefined scheme

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm trying to create some choropleth maps of one variable (say `var1`) for different values of a second variable (say `var2`) using a `UserDefined` scheme, so that the bins remain the same for all maps. However, for some values of `var2`, GeoPandas skips one of the categories - and strangely omits the middle colour from the list I'm passing. Please see example below:

[image: Image with bins as expected]

[image: Image with missing bin]

My code looks like this

```py
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

list_colours = [
    "#004c6d",
    "#628199",
    "#abbac7",
    "#f6f6f6",
    "#f3bcbc",
    "#e88184",
    "#d43d51",
]
list_leg_labels = [
    "Large decline",
    "Moderate decline",
    "Small decline",
    "No change",
    "Small increase",
    "Moderate increase",
    "Large increase",
]
bins = [-20, -10, -1, 1, 10, 20]
cmap = ListedColormap(list_colours)
scheme = "UserDefined"
bbox_to_anchor = (0.225, 0.26)
figsize = (20, 20)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_to_plot.plot(
    var1,
    ax=ax,
    linewidth=0.2,
    cmap=cmap,
    scheme=scheme,
    classification_kwds=dict(bins=bins),
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds={
        "bbox_to_anchor": bbox_to_anchor,
        "borderaxespad": 0,
        "fontsize": 9,
        "ncol": 1,
        "frameon": False,
    },
    zorder=1,
)
```

I was expecting the 7 bin classification to be consistent across maps, but instead a bin gets skipped in some cases.

Comment: This looks like a bug in GeoPandas. Can you report it to https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues with some example data?

Comment: Thank you, will do. If anyone stumbles upon this in the meantime, a workaround can be found here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225102/geopandas-legend-not-showing-bins-for-which-there-are-zero-observations-in-datas